# How can we find all $x\in\mathbb R$ such that $x^3 + 5x^2 = -6x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am to write the following set by listing its elements instead of set builder notation.

$$\{x\in\mathbb{R}\ |\  x^3 + 5x^2 = -6x\}$$

the answer is $\{-3, -2\}$. I arrived at this answer by making a guess and plugging things into the conditional equation. Is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: There's no difference compare to your previous question: $x^3+5x^2+6x=0\Leftrightarrow x(x^2+5x+6)=0$, exactly the same as your previous question.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I asked it out of context last time so I thought it might be different.

Comment: You might want to check this [tour page](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) as a guide for new users. If you see an answer that is most helpful for your problem, you can [accept that answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to get some [points](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: The correct answer is $\{-3,-2,0\}.$

Comment: You left out zero.  Rewrite as $x^3 + 5x^2 + 6x = 0$.  Factor out the $x$ as $x(x^2 +5x + 6) = 0$ so $x = 0$ and the solutions to $x^2 +5x + 6 = 0$ are the three solutions.  Factor, complete the square, or use quadratic formula to solve $x^2 + 5x + 6 = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

\begin{align}
x^3+5x^2=-6x &\Leftrightarrow x^3+5x^2+6x=0 \\
&\Leftrightarrow x(x^2+5x+6)=0\\
&\Leftrightarrow x=0\ \text{  or }\ x^2+5x+6=0\\
&\Leftrightarrow x=0\ \text{  or }\ (x+2)(x+3)=0
\end{align}

Comment: Their "previous question" was deleted. You may need to alter your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you see *all* $x$'s in an equation, understand that $x=0$ is surely a solution and then factorise.

So 
$x^3 +5x^2 + 6x = 0 \implies x(x^2 + 5x + 6)=0  \implies (x+2)(x+3)x=0 \implies x=0 $ or $x=-2$ or $x=-3$